# How can I predetermine the size of a malloc to concatenate an array of strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers

> Implement the append function that has the prototype below. The function returns a string that represents the concatenation of all the strings present in an array of strings. For this problem, you can assume the end of the parameter array is marked by `NULL`. You need to allocate memory for the resulting string.  You may not modify the array parameter.
>
> ```
> char* append(char *data[]);
> ```

I don't understand how to determine the size to `malloc` the pointer.

Comment: Loop over it and count the characters until you find the terminator. But note that this signature is bad. You'll need an additional argument for the `char*` array size.

Comment: You need to compute that size before allocating the memory zone

Comment: @MichaelPittino: the `data` parameter is an array of pointers ended by `NULL`

Comment: Ah, right. Well then all he needs to do is loop over the array of char-pointers and then loop over each individual char-pointer.

Comment: Do you understand how to create a dynamically allocated copy of a single string (i.e. something like `char *mkcopy(char *str)`)?

Comment: @Michael. Or use `strlen` presumably.

Comment: Basically, you will simply `strlen` each of the strings in `*data[]` and keep a running total insuring you allocate at least `+1` for the *nul-terminaing* character at each allocation/concatenation. You can do it in a single-loop with `realloc` or loop over the pointers first and `malloc` all at once.

Comment: Use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/?kw=strlen) to obtain the length of the string

Comment: @melpomene - you mean by way of a function prototype exampe? `mkcopy`? (to be implemented via `malloc/strcpy` or `strdup`)?

Answer (score 1):

An approach that goes through the strings twice seems good.

The first pass counts the sum of the lengths:

```
size_t len = 0;
for (char** pstr = data; *pstr; pstr++)
    len += strlen(*pstr);
```

The second pass concatenates all the strings:

```
char *str = malloc(len + 1);
str[0] = '\0';
for (char** pstr = data; *pstr; pstr++)
    strcat(str, *pstr);
return str;
```

You can optimize the concatenation part by storing the end point of the last concatenation:

```
char *str = malloc(len + 1);
str[0] = '\0';

char *p = str;
for (char** pstr = data; *pstr; pstr++) {
    strcat(p, *pstr);
    p += strlen(*pstr);
}
```

Comment: Missing check for overflow, missing check for `malloc` failing, assignment to `str[len]` is redundant, copying loop has O(n^2) performance. Would not recommend.

Comment: @melpomene I don't understand the O(n^2) performance. How can you do it without going through all the strings? Also what is `n`?

Comment: `n` is the number of strings. See https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/ for a detailed explanation.

Comment: That's right, I never thought about it, but that's actually true. @melpomene how do you think one could avoid this since that `strcat` only returns the `*dest` pointer? Should the strings be manually concatenated?

Comment: WTF? Is no one reading the article I linked to? Not only does it explain the problem, it also shows a solution that runs in linear time.

Comment: @melpomene you're right ahah, my bad there, thinking too fast without reading.

Comment: @melpomene OK, finally got it. My dumb head. Is it fixed now? (not talking about the contant hidden behind the big O)

Comment: No, your "optimized" version is identical to the other code.

Comment: @melpomene I forgot `strcat()` again :( It should look good (look linear) now.

Comment: Yes, that looks better. Note that you could replace `strcat` by `strcpy` in your last version because your code keeps the invariant that `p` always points at a NUL byte.

Comment: Last code snippet is good yet the needed `p[0] = 0;` or `str[0] = 0;` is implied and not shown.  Recommend to add it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to know the size of one string, you can use `strlen` from the library `string.h`. If you want to calculate the sum of all the sizes you can just use a loop and sum up all the `strlen`s, and add `1` for the terminal `NUL` character, like this:

```
char* append(char *data[]) {
    char **cur, *res;
    size_t len = 0;

    for (cur = data; *cur != NULL; *cur++)
        len += strlen(*cur);

    res = malloc(len + 1);

    // Now you can concatenate the strings...
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to check that the pointer returned by `malloc` is valid (i.e. not `NULL`).

Comment: `*cur++` parses as `*(cur++)`. The `*` does nothing.

Comment: Missing check for overflow, missing check for `malloc` failing.

Comment: @melpomene you mean overflow of the `size_t` for a possibly very long array of long strings? This doesn't seem like that kind of homework... as per the `malloc` check, I know, but op just asked how to calculate the size, nothing more (added a note).